# Object component as Prop React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I Have a type Data:

export type Data =
{

```
    id:Number;
    name:String;
    username:String;
    email:String;
    phone:String;
    website:String;

}
```

I wanna fetch data from a api. I'm using typescript so Data is a prop:

```
const App  = ()=>{
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1";
 
  const [userData, setUserData] =  useState<Data[]>([]);

  const getUserData = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let json = await response.json();
    setUserData(json);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>User Data</h2>
   
          <div>
            {userData.map( (item,index)=>{
             return(
              <div key={index}>
               <strong>Name: </strong>
            {item.name}
         
            <strong>Website: </strong>
            {item.website}
         
         
            <strong>Email: </strong>
            {item.email}
         
         
            <strong>Phone: </strong>
            {item.phone}
            </div>
             )

            } )}
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

I am getting an error in my code 'userData.map' is not a function  and i don´t wanna use `setUserData([json])`.
Is there an alternative?

Comment: If `json` is an array of `Data`, then what else are you going to do with it other than to use a `map`? You don't show any JSX at all, so we don't know where that is supposed to go.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Now given the actual error message and how your JSX looks, the answer is simple: handle when `userData` is undefined! `{userData !== undefined && userData.map(...` is one way.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the endpoint but if you are getting a single Data element from it you can:

- store the data doing `setUserData([json])`, this is perfectly fine and correct. You could also create the array first then push the data but that is really just making the code longer.
- Change how you store the data as you don't have an array of elements so you can do this instead:

```
const App  = ()=>{
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1";
 
  const [userData, setUserData] =  useState<Data | undefined >(undefined);

  const getUserData = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let json = await response.json();
    setUserData(json);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>User Data</h2>
   
          <div>
            {userData ? (<div>
               <strong>Name: </strong>
            {userData.name}
         
            <strong>Website: </strong>
            {userData.website}
         
         
            <strong>Email: </strong>
            {userData.email}
         
         
            <strong>Phone: </strong>
            {userData.phone}
            </div>
             ) : null
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

---

Old answer to previous version of the question

If json has the shape `Data[]` (i.e. returns multiple objects) you just need to do `setUserData(json)`. no need to do a map to set the data on the state.

If instead json has the shape `Data` (i.e. returns a single object) then you need to set that object in an array before setting that to state. The more direct way is as you suggest at the end to use `setUserData([json])` but you could also create the array first and push the data later to the array, something like this:

```
let json = data;
const dataArray = [];
dataArray.push(json);
setUserData(dataArray);
```

It would be better if you can be a bit more specific about::

- The return type of the endpoint
- What you want to achieve in general, to store the data in the state as it is?, store it as an array? something else? Why was relevant to use `.map`

Comment: Can you give more context, as to why you can't use userData.map() ?

Comment: In the example you can't use userData.map because I am stating that the assumption is userData is not an array